# NetSuite: Online Customer Form

Tags: forms, email, netsuite, custom-fields

I'm looking to create an Online Customer Form that won't create a lead in NetSuite nor update an existing customer record. Specifically, I want to be sent an email through a form without having to use a third-party. If NetSuite supported PHP, I could program the email script myself.

I'm looking to create a "website review form" via Online Customer Form.

NetSuite support hasn't been helpful in giving me an AnswerID to find and read through; they sent me the usual scripted response for anyone who's asking a question.

I hope that I am clarifying this as much as possible; they don't seem to understand me in the NetSuite forums in what I am trying to accomplish.

I need to create certain fields so that I can get the necessary information:

- review headline
- Rating
- Comments (this is a default field)
- Pros
- Cons
- Recommend?
- nickname
- location
- email (this is a default field)

When viewing the "set up workflow" subtab, would I uncheck "Allow update", "Allow update on customer record" and "allow update on contact record"?

If yes, great! then all I need to do is figure out how to add the additional fields.

Answer (score 1):

The Online Forms functionality is *specifically* for automatically creating and updating records in your account. If you don't want this to happen, you'll need a different solution instead of an Online Form.

If you are familiar with SuiteScript, you can build and publish your own form using an "External Suitelet."

If support and the forums aren't helping you out enough, check out the free [NetSuite Professionals Slack group](http://netsuiteprofessionals.com/).

Comment: Is it possible to have the form for creating purchase orders? How would I go about creating an external form for creating a purchase order record?